# Passing django variable to html javascript function in served file

Tags: javascript, django, render, onload

This is very odd and illogical. I serve an html file using the django code below. The javascript code works if pn is an integer, ex. 612, but fails if it is a string, ex. U612. What the heck?

Django views.py:

```
context = {'pattoload' : str(pn)}
t = TemplateResponse(request, 'viewer/index.html', context)
t.render()
return t
```

Javascript index.html:

```
window.onload=function(){
var pn = String({{pattoload}});
alert(pn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the downvotes. I tried to solve this problem and eventually did (see answer below) but for me it was quite difficult. That means that there are others out there like me who will benefit from it. So please upvote, not downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the answer is as follows in javascript:

```
var pn = "{{pattoload}}";
```

This was not obvious to me and I am glad to have stumbled across it.